# Assigning color codes manually in Grouped scatter plot with Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, scatter-plot

I am trying to create an interactive scatter plot with plotly and also assign color manually but it keep using the column used for grouping the data (color column-Orl) to create the color instead of the one I assigned manually. The Orl column consist of the following, w,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v.

```
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html


df1 = data_plot
df1["Oyl"] = df1["Oyl"].astype(str)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Pt': [22, 55,44,22,19,14,48,53,44,19,6,62,65,6,30],
                    'Pl': [38,38,42,40,40,42,74,84,86,102,100, 64,72,80,92],
                    'Oyl': [27,21,21,27,27,27,21,21,33,22,22,33,21], size=20, replace=True)}


fig_ = px.scatter(df1, x="Pt", y="Pl", color="Oyl",
                  hover_data=['H#', 'FM', 'O'], 
                 color_discrete_map=dict({"21":"#005900","22":"#00FF00",'27':'#FF8000','33':'#00FFFF'}))




fig_.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited because the sample data has been added, the data referring to the color has been changed from a string to a numeric string. type conversion in the pandas series, I do not have a reason why `df[col].astype(str)` is not converted. If I did it with a type string it could be converted to a string. the apply function converts it to str as is.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Pt': [22,55,44,22,19,14,48,53,44,19,6,62,65,6,30],
                    'Pl': [38,38,42,40,40,42,74,84,86,102,100,64,72,80,92],
                    'Oyl': [27,21,21,27,27,27,21,21,33,22,22,33,21,21,27]})
df1["Oyl"] = df1["Oyl"].astype('str')
#df1["Oyl"] = df1["Oyl"].apply(str)

fig_ = px.scatter(df1,
                  x="Pt",
                  y="Pl",
                  color="Oyl",
                  #hover_data=['H#', 'FM', 'O'],
                  color_discrete_map=dict({"21":"#005900","22":"#00FF00",'27':'#FF8000','33':'#00FFFF'}))
fig_.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/13107804/r-beginners,I just included a sample of my dataframe. I am expecting datapoints with category 22 to return light green (as indicated by the hex code) but it is returning a different color from the one I assigned it. Thanks

Comment: @stackoverflow.com/users/13107804/r-beginners, I tried the exact same thing on my dataframe (csv file), it is seeing the OYL column as object and not string. The reason I am using plotly is because matplot cant create interactive plot. Is there another way to fix the color assigning issue. Thanks

Comment: In pandas, if the target column is an object type, it contains a string. Is it possible to run the code in my answer only and get the assignment? If the result is the same, it could be environmental or another factor.